# If a step fails in a test case but test cases passes , extent report shows whole test case as failed even though final status of test case is passed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using DataProvider for my test cases, and with one of the data a step fails in test case but test case passes, testNG shows the test case as passed but extent report show it as failed. [Extent Report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az2HL.png)

Comment: Don't want your software running on anything that I have to fly in.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the `reportStep("Sample Test", "pass");` in each testcase.

eg:

```
@test
public void verifylogin(){
reportStep("UserName entered successfully", "pass");
}

@test
public void verifylogin(){
reportStep("Email entered successfully", "pass");
}
```

So that you got the output like this

[image: 1]